# RSA Key needs to be regenerated

Tags: c#, xml, iis

Need an assist on an issue I am having with an RSA key.   I generate a RSA key through C# code on a server with a key container name I define such as "CustKey".   I get back the key XML string just fine and I can connect an application to it using that key.   I have an API that is generating the key through an endpoint.   If I redeploy the API my application that uses the public key stops working on decoding it.   I have to run again the same code to create the key and the encrypted string is exactly the same every time I regenerate it and then the consuming app works fine again.  It seems to happen when either the app pool recycles but I have it turned off recycling but the publish I stop and start the IIS API site.   Any idea how to keep the key working and why I have to regenerate it but it uses the same key encrypted value each time.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples of your code would greatly help to understand what's going on. I can only speculate at this point that you're trying to decode your message with public key instead of private one.

Firstly, you have to have two paired keys:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
string publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
string privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
```

Secondly, you have to give your public key to all people who wants to send a secret message to you:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
string secretMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(openMessage), false));
```

And finally, when you recieve a secret message only you can decode it because only you have a private key which is paired to public one:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
string revealedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(secretMessage), false));
```